# Mixing pre-created content type blocks on the same page?

Tags: views

I'm trying to figure out if something like this is possible in Drupal:

- The general idea is creation of a free-form content page where I could mix and edit several pre-created content "blocks"
- I would pre-create several custom content types (for example, a content type with fields for an image and a line of text; and another content type with fields for two images)
- then want to be able to create a new content where I would add these pre-created content types to build free-form structures out of them, basically, creating a matrix of content where each individual block would consist of fixed fields, and where there blocks can be mixed in any number or order.

For those who might by familiar with CraftCMS, their [Matrix functionality](https://craftcms.com/features/matrix) is exactly what I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to replicate in Drupal.

At a minimum, just a knowledge of possibility/viability of this approach is fine. But if someone could point to into the right direction for further research, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) and / or [paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) but there are many other options.

Comment: Oh! This is perfect! Paragraphs seems to be exactly what I'm looking for! Thanks!